# How to save object instance to a variable in Python

Tags: python, class, object, instances

I have an instance of a class that I want to save in a different variable, so that I can make changes to the original without the state stored in the other variable being affected.

However, any changes I make to the original object (nn) is replicated in the second object (nn_2).

Code:

```
nn_2 = nn
nn_2.LEARNING_RATE = 3
nn.LEARNING_RATE = 1
print(nn_2.LEARNING_RATE)
print(nn.LEARNING_RATE)
```

Output:

```
1
1
```

What would be the way of achieving this?

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for this! I was searching how to save an instance rather than copy which is probably why I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `copy.deepcopy()` to copy objects so that it doesn't link to the same object.

```
from copy import deepcopy

nn_2 = deepcopy(nn)
nn_2.LEARNING_RATE = 3
nn.LEARNING_RATE = 1
print(nn_2.LEARNING_RATE)
print(nn.LEARNING_RATE) # should be different now
```

Comment: Thank you, that was perfect!